# assign zero to item in char array

Tags: arrays, c

I have some materials showing this code. what does code means by making these assignments?

```c
char inputfilename[128];
inputfilename[0] = 0;

char *argv[128];
*argv[1] = 0;
```

Comment: what exactly you want to know..... its self explanatory?

Comment: Are these two pairs of lines truly the only lines in some function? Or have you taken these lines out of context?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am a beginner of C.

Comment: That's not the only lines of some function, that's the assigning part.

Answer (score 1):

In C, character arrays are terminated by a null character (value 0). In both cases in your example, the code initializes the strings to "empty" (with a terminator in the first element). This would prove useful in any subsequent string operations (strcat, strcpy, etc.).

Comment: That's what I want to know. Thank you!

Comment: The second one is undefined behavior since the pointers in the array are not initialized.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: good point - I'll note that in my answer. Well, I would have, except the topic got closed...